# Изменение полей Django flatpages

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Могу ли я в админке в форму создания flatpage добавить какие то свои поля? Например мне нужно заместо поля content несколько других текстовых полей. Как это можно сделать? Документацию читал, но допереть всё равно не могу как это работает... Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто [унаследовать](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) собственную модель от `FlatPage`:

```
class ExtendedFlatPage(FlatPage):
    additional_field = models.CharField('Дополнительное поле', max_length=100)

@admin.register(FlatPage)
class ExtendedFlatPageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('url', 'title', 'content', 'additional_field', 'sites')}),
        (_('Advanced options'), {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': (
                'registration_required',
                'template_name',
            ),
        }),
    )
```